# How to extract XML attributes using XPath for Logstash

Tags: xml, elasticsearch, xpath, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm trying to parse below XML to get all classname, name,failure and error message. But I'm unable to extract the individual xml elements using the xpath. Can someone point me where am I going wrong?

```
<testsuite errors="1" failures="1">
    <testcase classname="junit.framework.TestSuite" name="com.webdashboard.Report" time="0.0">
           <failure message="Login failed: User labuser"></failure>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="junit.framework.TestSuite" name="com.webdashboard.Report" time="0.002">
           <error message="no service found defining interface"> </error>
    </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

here is my configuration file to extract classname. But it's not working :(

```
input {
 file {
  path => "/home/jar/Documents/xml/*.xml"
  start_position => beginning
  codec => multiline
  {
   pattern => "^<\?testsuite .*\>"
   negate => true
   what => "previous"
  }
 }
}

filter {
  xml {
   source => "src"
   target => "testsuite"
   xpath =>
   [
    "//testcase/@classname", "classname"
   ]
}

if "message" in [tags] {
          drop { }
}


date {
    match => [ "date" , "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" ]
    timezone => "Europe/Amsterdam"
}

}

output {
 file {
        path => "/home/jar/Documents/xml/output2.txt"
  }
}
```